# MonogoDB service cannot start after storage extension under Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04

Recently I extended my server's storage size. Everything else is working fine, but I cannot manage to start MongoDB by `sudo service mongodb start`. After I typed in this command, it prompted `mongodb start/running, process 1279`. It looks OK. but when I check the status of the service, it shows the service is not running. So I checked the `mongodb.log`. What I found is the service will start, and after a while, the service process will receive a signal 2: `Thu Jun  6 06:09:06.963 got signal 2 (Interrupt), will terminate after current cmd ends`.

I also try to configure the mongodb to output more verbose log, but it didn't help me to figure out the source if the interruption.

Now I can only start MongoDB with `sudo mongod --config /path/to/conf_file`. Anyone knows how to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe some setting in /etc/default/mongodb causes the problem. Try sourcing it and the run the mongod on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

What I did was being sure that all the files and directories in your /var/lib/mongodb/ folder (or whichever folder dbpath points to) belong to the mongodb user and mongodb group.

```
cd /var/lib/mongodb/
sudo chown -R mongodb *
sudo chgrp -R mongodb *
```

Then you can remove the lock, repair the database and restart the daemon:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock   
sudo -u mongodb mongod --config /etc/mongodb.conf --repair 
sudo service mongodb start
```